# How to include a build timestamp in a VC++ project?

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-c++

I am converting a makefile project into a Visual Studio VC++ project.  It's actually C source code.

One of the statements I have in my makefile is:

```
echo char * gLibraryBuildSig ="%DATE% %TIME%"; > BuildTimestamp.c
```

This produces a C source file with a single line in it:

```
char * gLibraryBuildSig ="Sun 08/23/2009 17:56:05.05";
```

In the makefile I then compile all the C source with cl.exe, and after linking, delete the BuildTimestamp.c file.  This gives me a global symbol that provides the  bubild time as a string.

How can I do the same thing in a VS2008 project?  Keep in mind it's not MSBuild.

I'm part-way there. To generate a C module at build time in Visual Studio, I just use the pre-build event.

[image]

How do I include that generated file into the compile, but also exclude it from source control and project management?

Or, is there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: FFWD 10 years , and ... I see nothing wrong with this approach. It is only it can be done as a macro -- `#define BUILD_TIMESTAMP __DATE__ " " __TIME__  `, in both C and C++  that actually is compile time constant (gasp!) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler (cl.exe) has predefined macros [`__DATE__` and `__TIME__`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.71).aspx), as well as `__TIMESTAMP__`. You can compile a file containing only these as a pre-link step.

Answer (score 1):

I might be 10 years late, but I like this simple approach. My solution is

1. my pre-build step:

   ```
    echo #define DBJ_BUILD_TIMESTAMP __DATE__ " " __TIME__  > build_time_stamp.inc
   ```
2. That little inc, contains a compile time constant in both C and C++. I usually include it in my `main.cpp`

   ```
    #include "build_time_stamp.inc"
   ```

Since it is generated on each build, it provokes (re)compilation of `main.cpp`

3. Usage might be

   ```
   printf( "\nBuild time stamp: "  DBJ_BUILD_TIMESTAMP );
   ```
4. If you do not what to be bothered by GIT to commit/sync/push, that inc file, after each build, simply do not include it in a project. In any case if you want to use it in some more complex scenario, simply keep it in a global constant:

   ```
    constexpr auto build_time_stamp = DBJ_BUILD_TIMESTAMP ;
   ```

Enjoy ...

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the preprocessor to include the generated file:

```
#include "BuildTimeStamp.c"
```

The file that includes this file can be one of the files in the project under source control.